# Looking for a more efficient way of doing many queries in mongoose-q

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-q

I'm using mongoose-q (a promise wrapper for the popular mongoose mongodb ORM for node.js).

However, I fell like maybe these nested promises are not much better than callbacks.

Is there a better way to do these queries?

```
User.findById(toFollowId)
    .execQ()
    .then(function(user){
        if (!user) return res.send(404);

        user.followers.addToSet(me);
        me.following.addToSet(user);

        me.saveQ()
            .then(function(me){
                user.saveQ()
                    .then(function(user){
                        getFollowerStats([me, user], function(err, data){
                            if ( err ) return res.json(400, err);

                            res.json(data);
                        });
                }).fail(function(err){
                    res.json(400, err);
                });
            })
            .fail(function(err){
                res.json(400, err);
            });
    }).fail(function(err){
        next(err);
    });
```

Comment: what you don't like about it? perfectly fine code as for me

Comment: Yes, i think it would be cleaner using named functions as callback parameters.

Comment: @monkeyinsight i don't like it because it still sufferes from `pyramid of doom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you reproduce the pyramid which is typical of callbacks?

I would suggest rewriting the code as follows. There is only one error handler (fail fn), check if it could fit your needs. Note you have to include the q library.

```
q = require('q');


User.findById(toFollowId)
    .execQ()
    .then(function(user){
        if (!user) return res.send(404);

        user.followers.addToSet(me);
        me.following.addToSet(user);

        return q.all([me.saveQ(), user.saveQ()]);
    })
    .spread(function(me, user){
        getFollowerStats([me, user], function(err, data){
            if ( err ) return res.json(400, err);

            res.json(data);
        });
    })
    .fail(function(err){
        next(err);
    });
```

A note regarding spread:

> If you have a promise for an array, you can use spread as a
>   replacement for then. The spread function “spreads” the values over
>   the arguments of the fulfillment handler. The rejection handler will
>   get called at the first sign of failure. That is, whichever of the
>   received promises fails first gets handled by the rejection handler.

See the doc (http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) for a complete description.

Here is an alternative using "then":

```
User.findById(toFollowId)
    .execQ()
    .then(function(user){
        if (!user) return res.send(404);

        user.followers.addToSet(me);
        me.following.addToSet(user);

        return q.all([me.saveQ(), user.saveQ()]);
    })
    .then(function(resolvedArray){
        var me = resolvedArray[0],
            user = resolvedArray[1];

        getFollowerStats([me, user], function(err, data){
            if ( err ) return res.json(400, err);

            res.json(data);
        });
    })
    .fail(function(err){
        next(err);
    });
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with info regarding 'spread' and added a version using 'then'